# How can I show/hide data and update the button label with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session-variables, web-development-server

I'm using Symfony 5.5 and I want to have a button that show/hide data when the user click on it.

My code was working but I've noticed that when I leave the page and came again after, the button wasn't working like expected (needed to click twice on it to activate it because the session variable wasn't reset). Now the session variable reset correctly but I can't hide my data anymore. Does someone have an idea on how to achieve that properly ?

```
#[Route('/user/setup')]
class UserSetupController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'user_setup_index', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function index(Request $request, SetupRepository $setupRepository): Response
    {
        // Get the connected user
        $connectedUser = $this->getUser();

        $filterForm = $this->addFilterForm($request, $setupRepository, $connectedUser);
        $showAllForm = $this->addShowAllForm($request, $setupRepository, $connectedUser);

        return $this->render('user_dashboard/user_setup/index.html.twig', [
            'setups' => $filterForm['setups'] ?? $showAllForm['setups'] ?? null,
            'filterForm' => $filterForm['filterForm'],
            'showAllForm' => $showAllForm['showAllForm'],
            'message' => $filterForm['message'] ?? $showAllForm['message'] ?? null,
        ]);
    }

    private function addShowAllForm(Request $request, SetupRepository $setupRepository, UserInterface $connectedUser) 
    {
        // Create a form to show all setups
        $showAllForm = $this->createForm(ShowAllType::class);
        $showAllForm->handleRequest($request);

        // Get the session
        $session = $request->getSession();
        // Get the value of the session variable
        $activated = $session->get('activated');
        
        // If the form is submitted and valid
        if ($showAllForm->isSubmitted() && $showAllForm->isValid()) {
            // Get the value of the session variable again (because it has changed since the form was submitted)
            $activated = $session->get('activated');
            
            // Change the value of the variable
            $session->set('activated', !$activated); 

            // If the form had already been submitted 
            if (!$activated) {
                // Get all setups of the user
                $setups = $setupRepository->findSetupByUser($connectedUser);
                
                // If the user has no setup, show a message
                if (empty($setups)) {
                    $message = "Tu n'as pas encore créé de setup";
                }
            } else { // If the form had not already been submitted, show no setup
                $setups = []; 
            }
        }

        return [
            'showAllForm' => $showAllForm->createView(),
            'setups' => $setups ?? null,
            'message' => $message ?? null,
        ];
    }
    // ....
}
```

```
class KernelRequestListener implements EventSubscriberInterface 
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onKernelRequest',
        ];
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event) {
        $request = $event->getRequest(); 
        $route = $request->attributes->get('_route'); 

        if ($route !== 'user_setup_index') {
            $session = $request->getSession(); 
            $session->set('activated', false); 
        }
    }
}
```